# text control allowing to use bitmaps and text together

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I am trying to create  chat application that support smylies,and since I am using textctrl to show text messages from users ,I want find a way to add smylies icons along with text just like any known chat application such as yahoo messanger or nimbuzz..
and if it is not possible with textctrl ,so what is the alternative .I am using wxpython for python 2.7 on windows 8.1 .please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [wxRichTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_rich_text_ctrl.html).

Comment: that is cool but how to align text right and center because wx.TE_RIGHT and wx.TE_CENTER is not working here ?

Comment: now it is fixed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767612/set-text-alignment-of-rich-text-ctrl/27771472#27771472/